# Auto connect wifi even when on wired in windows 8

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8

Usually people need to know how to disable the wifi automatically when on a wired connection. But I actually need to know how to make windows (8) automatically connect to wifi when there's already a wired connection. I made sure to set "automatically connect to this network" in my wireless network settings.

On boot it still only connects to the wired connection, and ignores my wifi - can I force the wifi connection?

Comment: Hmm, tough one. You could change the priority of your network cards but that still doesn't help. I have set the priority to the WiFi card to be higher than that of the wired network card and it did not help. It looks like the wired connections always trump the wireless ones. Which makes sense, if you think about it.

Comment: Well, it makes sense from one point of view, I'll agree with you there. But in my case I have port forwards to services on my server pointing to the ip of the WiFi card. Sometimes I pull the wired connection for less clutter, so I don't want to have to change the port forwards every time I do this :(